# iOS 17.2 breaking AppIntents and shortcuts

Tags: ios, swift, android-intent, shortcut, appintents

I have an app that relies heavily on AppIntents and Shortcuts and it seems like the latest iOS update broke those but I can't quite figure out what's the issue. The is that no matter what parameter I pick, when running the shortcut it always uses the `defaultResult()`

Here's an example AppEntity:

```swift
    struct IntentBrokerAppEntity: AppEntity {
        static var typeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: "Intent Broker")
    
        @Property(title: "Name")
        var name: String?
    
        @Property(title: "Ip")
        var ip: String?
    
        @Property(title: "Port")
        var port: String?
    
        @Property(title: "Username")
        var username: String?
    
        @Property(title: "Password")
        var password: String?
    
        @Property(title: "Tls")
        var tls: Bool?
    
        struct IntentBrokerAppEntityQuery: EntityQuery {
            func entities(for identifiers: [IntentBrokerAppEntity.ID]) async throws -> [IntentBrokerAppEntity] {
                return try await suggestedEntities().filter { identifiers.contains($0.id) }
            }
    
            func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [IntentBrokerAppEntity] {
                let context = PersistenceController.shared.viewContext
                let brokerService = BrokerService(context: context)
                return brokerService.getFavorites().map { IntentBrokerAppEntity(broker: $0) }
            }
            
            func defaultResult() async -> IntentBrokerAppEntity? {
                try? await suggestedEntities().first
            }
        }
        static var defaultQuery = IntentBrokerAppEntityQuery()
    
        var id: String
        var displayString: String
        var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
            DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(displayString)")
        }
    ...
```

This used to work perfectly fine before 17.2, but now instead of choosing the entity the user picked it always falls back to `defaultResult()`.

In the console I get this warning

> Failed to build EntityIdentifier. IntentBrokerAppEntity is not a
> registered AppEntity identifier

But I'm not sure if that's related. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on here? Input much appreciated!